# Understanding Android support libraries

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am currently reading up on the Android Support Libraries (I am aware of Jetpack/AndroisX, but can't use them yet).

I understand that v7 depends on v4, so with adding v7 I get v4 and what comes with v7. What I don't understand are the other `v<number>` like v8, v13. Do they extend v7? In general, if I start a new application with Android Support Libraries, would I use the highest `v<number>` or still v7?

Comment: They all support only from Min SDK 16+ anyway if I remember correctly (might be 14+ but I think they have increased it).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - the [documentation says 14+](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library#api-versions)

Comment: v8 and v13 are not even mentioned anywhere in the linked documentation

Comment: @0X0nosugar Please see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages it mentions v8, v13 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think in v4, v7, v13 as the name of the library and not like an actual "version". In a certain way, they are just the name of the library.

Each Android Support Library comes with its own set of sub-libraries. Those sub-libraries can be found in one library (v7, for example) and therefore, you can't just use the highest number (if you try to use v13 you get an error).

`CardView` for example. You add it to your project with `com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0`. It is only found in the v7 library. If you try to import via `com.android.support:cardview-v13:28.0.0`, you will get an error.

Some classes can be found in more than one library (e.g. `Fragments`). They can be found in v4 and also on v13. However, each of those classes have a different implementation. So, you should use v4 or v13 according to your project/necessity. You don't need to simply use the highest number because they are just names... not an actual version.

If you simple use v13, for example, you won't get v7 sub-libraries because the v13 library does not depends of the v7 library.

Comment: Perfect answer, well understandable. Thank you! For others: The first sentence is the most important one. Don't think of v7, v13 etc. as versions, but only as names. There are only historical reasons for these strange names...